# If statement within a map dictionary in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I have a dictionary containing objects with cards. I would only like to display each card if the current user value is equal to the stored user value. IE, if the a given user created that card.

```
           <CardDeck>
            {this.props.homeTdps.map(function (tdp, key) {
              if ({currentUser.username} == {this.props.tdpDetail.created_by.username})
                return (
                  <Card.Link key={key} href={`/tdps/${tdp.id}/`} style={{ minWidth: '20rem', maxWidth: '20rem' }}>
                    <Card.Body>
                      <Card.Title>{tdp.part_name}</Card.Title>
                      <Card.Text>{tdp.description}</Card.Text>
                      <Button variant="primary">Download</Button>
                    </Card.Body>
                  </Card.Link>
                );
              // }
            })}
          </CardDeck>
```

I am having trouble however syntatically with the  the third line:

```
if ({currentUser.username} == {this.props.tdpDetail.created_by.username})
```

My current error is as follows...
[image]

Any solution is appreciated,

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have also tried removing the curly brackets from the 3rd line:

```
if (currentUser.username == this.props.tdpDetail.created_by.username)
```

I then get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined".

However, when I print the two values within a header like so, they both print just fine (and the users are the same value).

```
<h3>{currentUser.username}</h3> 
<h3>{this.props.tdpDetail.created_by.username}</h3>
```

Comment: `if (currentUser.username == this.props.tdpDetail.created_by.username)`

Comment: Change it to `if (currentUser.username == this.props.tdpDetail.created_by.username)` and try.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that. However I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined". However, when I print the two values within a header, they both print just fine (and the users are the same value).   <h3>{currentUser.username}</h3>
          <h3>{this.props.tdpDetail.created_by.username}</h3>

Comment: @EmmanuelHuff are you using a functional component or a class component?

Comment: @near Class components with React Redux

Comment: Ternary operator is simple to use inside jsx.

Comment: @EmmanuelHuff Are you rendering the CardDeck component in the render function or are you trying to do it in a separate function?

Comment: post your full class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- remove the curly bracets from your if statement;
- use arrow function at `map` to properly bind `this` to your component Class:

  ```
        {this.props.homeTdps.map((tdp, key) => {
          if (currentUser.username == this.props.tdpDetail.created_by.username)
            return (
              <Card.Link key={key} href={`/tdps/${tdp.id}/`} style={{ minWidth: '20rem', maxWidth: '20rem' }}>
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{tdp.part_name}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Text>{tdp.description}</Card.Text>
                  <Button variant="primary">Download</Button>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card.Link>
            );
          // }
        })}
  ```

Comment: thank you! That did it. Do you mind explaining to me why the "=>" is needed to bind?

Comment: you are welcome. `this` inside a function declaration like `function() {}` is not binded to its context, meanwhile an arrow function always bind the context where it's declared. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable